# Partition TPL Tasks in ASP.NET 4.0 for WCF Service

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net, task-parallel-library

I would like to know if using partition code like this is ok to do to partition tasks in ASP.NET 4.0 inside of a WCF service.  My goal with this code is to try to do non-blocking calls without spinning up too many concurrent tasks on the server.

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<string>> ExecuteTasks(IEnumerable<string> files)
    {
        ConcurrentBag<string> bag = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

        await Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(Partitioner.Create(files).GetPartitions(5).Select(partition => Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
       {
           using (partition)
           {
               while (partition.MoveNext())
               {
                    string test = string.Format("File {2} is executing in thread {0} and {3} in background at {1}", 
                                               Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, 
                                                DateTime.Now, partition.Current, 
                                                Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground);
                   Console.WriteLine(test);
                   bag.Add(test);
               }
           }
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)).ToArray(), _ => { });

        return bag.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: does the output need to match the same order as the input?  You could look at that TPL DataFlow blocks which naturally support TPL dataflow and limiting.  Because of the async nature I'm not sure they would guarantee output order would match input order.  but that could be work around with a sort at the end.

Comment: It does not need to match the same order.

Comment: Sorry I had wrote up an example to use the dataflow blocks but then saw you are targeting .,net 4.0.  I believe the dataflow blocks only came out as CTP for .net 4.0.

Comment: @CharlesNRice: it seems that there is a version of dataflow bocks for .net 4.0 available: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338907/where-can-i-find-a-tpl-dataflow-version-for-4-0

Answer (score 1):

#### Specification

There are a couple of strategies available to you depending on what exactly you mean with

> *"not spinning up too many concurrent tasks"*

#### Possible Strategies

1. If you want a maximum allowed number of tasks to be processed concurrently on the server, regardless of this method, assuming you are using the default task scheduler, you can [set the maximum number of threads of the .NET ThreadPool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads?view=netframework-4.8).
2. If you want a maximum allowed number of tasks to be processed concurrently for this given scenario, leaving the other task scheduling on the server alone, you can:

   - [implement a custom TaskScheduler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) with its own dedicated thread pool. In .NET Framework you might also [implement a custom SynchronizationContext](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext?view=netframework-4.8) instead. It's a lower level than the scheduler and you can always create a `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();`.
   - [use a SemaphoreSlim](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netframework-4.8) to limit the number of tasks that actually perform work concurrently. Note that this could still lead to more threads than your threshold to be activated, however, only the specified threshold amount of threads would actually be performing work.
   - Use [JanDotNet's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/172819/200620) `Parallel` with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` approach within a single `Task`. Note that this changes the affinity from threads to processors. Not sure whether this is what you are looking for. But at least it's a possibility, and non-blocking because wrapped inside a `Task`.

Answer (score 0):

TPL has a method `Parallel.ForEach` that allows to restrict the degree of parallelism:

```
var options = new ParallelOptions();
options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5;

Parallel.ForEach(files, options, file => { /* process file */});
```

Comment: That is a blocking call so don't want to use that.  This is mirror that parallelism with partitions without blocking the threadpool.